# Is a "Try / Except ValueError UNLESS" possible?

Tags: exception, try-catch, except, valueerror

I'm new to python and have been trying like hell for the past few hours to figure out how to get this to work properly...

It's *very* simple code I'm sure, but I'm just not getting it.

It should be pretty self-explanatory below in the code, but basically I'm asking a user to input the date of an event as an 'int' and if it's not a number, then ask them to try again... *UNLESS* it's a "?"

```
while True:
    date = None
    street = str(input('Name of street?: ').title())
    city = str(input("In what city?: ").title())
    while True:
        try:
            year = int(input("Date of event? (or '?'): "))
            if date == "?":
                break
        except Exception:
            print("That's not a date, try again!")
            continue
        break
```

It seems that it's not even getting to see *IF* because it gets caught by the 'except' before it can.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to display help or something when a '?' is input, then just call the function to display the help where you have the break currently.

```
if date == "?":
    display_help()
    continue
```

Then, split reading the input and processing it into two steps.

```
in = input("Date of event? (or '?'): ")
if in == "?":
    display_help()
    continue
year = int(in)
```

Also, you ask for a date but then assume that a year is entered, I'd be more explicit in your promt.

"Please enter the year of the event, ex: 1998"
or whatever form you actually want it in.

Comment: what do you want to happen when you encounter a ?

Comment: When user enters "?", it should bypass the ValueError exception and return the "?" value in place of any int that would be required otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Trying using a valueError exception. Also I think in your post you mentioned you wanted to enter a date as integer, so I replaced year with the date. If you wanted the year to be an integer you can replace the variable date with year. If you wanted to the user to enter a year, day and month then this program needs to be redesigned a bit.

```
date = None
street = str(input('Name of street?: ').title())
city = str(input("In what city?: ").title())
while True:
    date = input("Date of event? (or '?'): ")
    if date == "?":
        break
    else:
        try:
            date = int(date)
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a date, try again!")
            continue
        break
```

Comment: But, regardless of the *type* of exception, wouldn’t it trigger it to overlook the “if” statement...? I haven’t tried it, but I believe it would... again, regardless of the type of exception

Comment: You are right. I reedited the code, but I am not sure if the OP wanted the user to enter a date or a year.  Maybe the year variable was a typo and he meant date.